# Which part of this contact form I have to change if I am supposed to set up this form for my own website?

Tags: css, forms, email, action, contacts

As an amateur who has never created/designed any kind of "form actions", I need help to use this form for a website I am currently designing. I feel okay with "CSS" and structure of the form itself. Just want to know which part of this contact form should be changed. Where to put my Email address?

```html
<div class="segment contact-form">
  <div class="center-wrap">
    <div class='gf_browser_unknown gform_wrapper holla-form_wrapper' id='gform_wrapper_1'>
      <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='gform_1' class='holla-form' action='http://mammothmedia.tv/contact/'>
        <div class='gform_body'>
          <ul id='gform_fields_1' class='gform_fields top_label form_sublabel_below description_below'>
            <li id='field_1_1' class='gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
              <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_1'>First Name<span class='gfield_required'>*</span>
              </label>
              <div class='ginput_container'>
                <input name='input_1' id='input_1_1' type='text' value='' class='medium' tabindex='1' />
              </div>
            </li>
            <li id='field_1_8' class='gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
              <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_8'>Last Name<span class='gfield_required'>*</span>
              </label>
              <div class='ginput_container'>
                <input name='input_8' id='input_1_8' type='text' value='' class='medium' tabindex='2' />
              </div>
            </li>
            <li id='field_1_2' class='gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
              <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_2'>Email<span class='gfield_required'>*</span>
              </label>
              <div class='ginput_container'>
                <input name='input_2' id='input_1_2' type='text' value='' class='medium' tabindex='3' />
              </div>
            </li>
            <li id='field_1_3' class='gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
              <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_3'>Phone</label>
              <div class='ginput_container'>
                <input name='input_3' id='input_1_3' type='text' value='' class='medium' tabindex='4' />
              </div>
            </li>
            <li id='field_1_6' class='gfield field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
              <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_6'>Budget Range</label>
              <div class='ginput_container'>
                <input name='input_6' id='input_1_6' type='text' value='' class='medium' tabindex='5' />
              </div>
            </li>
            <li id='field_1_5' class='gfield ginput_textarea field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
              <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_5'>Comments</label>
              <div class='ginput_container'>
                <textarea name='input_5' id='input_1_5' class='textarea medium' tabindex='6' rows='10' cols='50'></textarea>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li id='field_1_7' class='gfield ginput_subscribe field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
              <label class='gfield_label'></label>
              <div class='ginput_container'>
                <ul class='gfield_checkbox' id='input_1_7'>
                  <li class='gchoice_1_7_1'>
                    <input name='input_7.1' type='checkbox' value='Subscribe to our newsletter' id='choice_1_7_1' tabindex='7' />
                    <label for='choice_1_7_1' id='label_1_7_1'>Subscribe to our newsletter</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li id='field_1_9' class='gfield gform_validation_container field_sublabel_below field_description_below'>
              <label class='gfield_label' for='input_1_9'>Comments</label>
              <div class='ginput_container'>
                <input name='input_9' id='input_1_9' type='text' value='' />
              </div>
              <div class='gfield_description'>This field is for validation purposes and should be left unchanged.</div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='gform_footer top_label'>
          <input type='submit' id='gform_submit_button_1' class='gform_button button' value='Submit' tabindex='8' onclick='if(window["gf_submitting_1"]){return false;}  window["gf_submitting_1"]=true;  ' />
          <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='is_submit_1' value='1' />
          <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_submit' value='1' />
          <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_unique_id' value='' />
          <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='state_1' value='WyJbXSIsIjA0OGE5MTQyNDdhM2NhZjFiMTc5Nzk5ZjM1ZTIzZjYzIl0=' />
          <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_target_page_number_1' id='gform_target_page_number_1' value='0' />
          <input type='hidden' class='gform_hidden' name='gform_source_page_number_1' id='gform_source_page_number_1' value='1' />
          <input type='hidden' name='gform_field_values' value='' />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(event, formId, currentPage) {
        if (formId == 1) {
          jQuery('#input_1_3').mask('(999) 999-9999').bind('keypress', function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
              jQuery(this).blur();
            }
          });
        }
      });
      jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_conditional_logic', function(event, formId, fields, isInit) {});
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      jQuery(document).ready(function({
            jQuery(document).trigger('gform_post_render', [1, 1])
          });
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to use this because this form uses a WordPress Plugin called [Gravity Form's](http://www.gravityforms.com/)

Also most form's use `PHP` and you wont be able to grab `PHP` from client side.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. So what do you suggest? Downloading and using those "downloadable" contact form from "template offering" websites?

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do. By the sound's of thing's you don't really know anything about code so I would probably recommend you get template. Especially if this is for a personal site of some sort. Alternately you could hire someone to make what it is you are after.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately my knowledge about coding is poor. I'm still learning. I can only edit (with the help of any editor that includes a wysiwyg... ha ha). Anyway, you helped a lot! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which server side language are you using? PHP, ASP.NET, etc? If you're trying to make a form that will send an email to an email address you'll have to set up some server side code. Right now it looks like it sends the form data to http://mammothmedia.tv/contact/ but configuring smtp for emailing is going to depend on the server side language you're using. On another note, your site looks really nice ;)

EDIT:
Check out: http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php , that oughta get you started.

Comment: Thank you so much, but as i already said, I am not familiar with contact forms and "java codings". I want a contact form exactly like http://mammothmedia.tv/contact/ but don't know where to find the "php feed" of this contact form to change the "mailto" of it into my "own" webmail. can you help please?